# setCompoundDrawables EditText Text Overlapping

Tags: android, android-edittext, drawable

I'm Implementing a `Drawable` as text at the start of my `EditText` using `setCompoundDrawables` but I'm getting incorrect results. What I need is for my text to start after the `Drawable` when typing but in stead I'm getting this

[image]

I have a `EditText` In a layout defined like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/control"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="4dp" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/field"
        style="@style/TextField"
        android:inputType="number" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I have to add a piece of text as a `Drawable` in the beginning of the `EditText`. So I convert Text to a `Drawable` using this `class`

```
public class TextDrawable extends Drawable {

    private final String text;
    private final Paint paint;

    public TextDrawable(String text) {
        this.text = text;
        this.paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#009999"));
        paint.setTextSize(30);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawText(text, 0, 6, paint);
    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
        paint.setAlpha(alpha);
    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
        paint.setColorFilter(cf);
    }

    @Override
    public int getOpacity() {
        return PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
    }
}
```

And I implement it here

```
final   EditText field   = (EditText) widget.findViewById(R.id.field);

field.setCompoundDrawables(new TextDrawable(this.label), null, null, null);
field.setText(this.value);
```

Am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT**

I tried using this method  `field.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.my_drawable, 0, 0, 0);` and it works but obviously I can't use it because the drawable isn't defined as a resource.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

so setBounds in your Drawable's ctor, or override getIntrinsicWidth(), you will need to check which one works

Comment: Thanks that worked. Just overrode getIntrinsicWidth() and returned the text width

Comment: Nope the set bounds only resized the Drawable, didn't change the start position

Answer (score 1):

You can do like that

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
```

Comment: That is only supported from Android Api v14. I need to support from api v8

Comment: Even if I'm mistaking @Rajan I cannot use that method because the text needs to be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Try do like this-

```
field.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(new TextDrawable(this.label), null, null, null);
```

You have to set the bounds.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've tried that before posting the question, no positive results. I think this might be close to the answer but something is missing.

Comment: If I use this method  `field.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.my_drawable, 0, 0, 0);` it works but obviously I can't use it because the drawable isn't defined as a resource.

Comment: I think, your text is not a drawable, that's why its not working for you here.